# ZF2 How to use Curl adapter by default for HTTP Client

Tags: zend-framework2

The Http Client in Zend 2 uses the Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket adapter by default. I want to change it, to use Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl adapter, but I want to do it in global configuration. So Every exteranl modules like los/losrecaptcha to works properly. Now using the Socket adapter, this module returns: `"Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection www.google.com: make sure the "sslcafile" or "sslcapath" option are properly set for the environment."`

How to set globaly the Client to use Curl Adapter? I tried to put in global.config something like this but I dont know how actualy

```
'di' => [
        'instance' => [
            'Zend\Http\Client' => [
                'options' => [
                    'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Are all instances of `Http\Client` being sourced from the service manager? or instantiated inline?

Comment: I use ZFC User and los and "los/losrecaptcha" module registration form is trying to comunicate with google via the Socket Adapter. I have to check out this

Comment: Disclaimer I am the author: use this, turnkey https://packagist.org/packages/saeven/zf2-circlical-recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are accessing the google url over https.

An alternative solution could be to properly configure your socket adapter to use a certificate. You can read on how to do that **[here in the `Client` documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.http.client.html#connecting-to-ssl-urls)**

### UPDATE

Doing some digging I found that you can configure the `LosReCaptcha` class to use ssl with a parameter. My guess is you don't need to do any customization (like setting a `Curl` adapter) in the `Client` class to make it work correctly, you should just pass the correct params when constructing your `LosReCaptcha` instance.

For example [the third argument `$params`](https://github.com/Lansoweb/LosReCaptcha/blob/master/src/LosReCaptcha/Service/ReCaptcha.php#L114) in the constructor is [an array with two keys `ssl` and `xhmtl`](https://github.com/Lansoweb/LosReCaptcha/blob/master/src/LosReCaptcha/Service/ReCaptcha.php#L74-79). The value for `ssl` is `false` by default, so my guess would be setting it to `true` should solve your issue.

```
$params = array('ssl' => true, 'xhtml' => false);
$captcha = new LosReCaptcha($siteKey, $secretKey, $params, /*...*/);
```